# flutter ColorScheme problem with some deprecated warnings

Tags: flutter, dart, color-scheme

I had some deprecated warnings in Theme  . the code before :

```
class myTheme {
static getTheme() => ThemeData(

  primaryColor: Colors.grey,
  primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  buttonColor:Colors.blueAccent,
  accentColor: Colors.blueGrey,
);
}
```

accentColor and buttonColor were deprecated so I changed it to :

```
class RevoCheckTheme {
 static getTheme() => ThemeData(

  primaryColor: Colors.grey,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  colorScheme:
  ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.grey)
      .copyWith(secondary: Colors.blueGrey)
      .copyWith(surface:Colors.blueAccent)
);
}
```

and now the the colors aren't the same as before , I think primarySwatch effects on other colors maybe . is it the right way to solve it or Im completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be

```dart
static getTheme() => ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.grey,
      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.grey)
          .copyWith(
              secondary: Colors.blueGrey,
              background: Colors.white,
              surface: Colors.blueAccent),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should edit it to

```
static getTheme() => ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.grey,
  // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.grey)
      .copyWith(
          secondary: Colors.blueGrey,
          background: Colors.white,
          surface: Colors.blueAccent),
);
```

- this will copy the old values for the required arguments of colorScheme and override the values you want (secondary, surface...)